# How is I2C signal integrity maintained over monitor cables for EDID?

Tags: i2c, signal-integrity

Computer monitors (and other similar display equipment) use the I2C protocol with 5V signal levels to send EDID information to the "host".

I2C's typical use case is for short connections on a PCB or between PCBs in an enclosure. I myself have needed to use I2C for long cable runs and I often have to use differential I2C in order to get good noise immunity.

Given the relatively long length of some monitor cables and the proximity of other high-frequency digital signals on the same cable, how is the reliability/immunity of the I2C EDID link ensured in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately not very exciting.

First of all the high frequency data lanes are differential pairs, so their currents will sum to zero in ideal case, and the differential pairs are shielded so they have practically zero effect to DDC bus.

And there are no other unshielded high frequency signals that could couple to DDC bus. Basically DDC and other wires just run paralllel without shielding in the wire.

The EDID itself has a specific data structure which includes a checksum to detect if host has read it correctly or not, and host can retry the read if there seems to be an error.